# Add a break to an unordered list with CSS when window width is less than 600px

Tags: css, list

If I have an unordered list that I am using for an icon menu like the menu seen in a word processor or text editor.  When the window gets below say 600px the icons get hidden and I want them to break down onto the next line.

```
<ul>
<li>Icon One</li>
<li>Icon twi</li>
<li>Icon three</li>
<li>Icon four</li>
<li>Icon five</li>
</ul>
```

This list is an inline list and I need it to break after the 4th item into two rows IF the window is less than 600px.

Is there a css solution to this without having to create a separate list or add another row?

i.e. something like this

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.listing {
display:inline;
}

.breakitem {
display:breakhere;
}

}
</style>



 <ul class="listing">
    <li>Icon One</li>
    <li>Icon twi</li>
    <li>Icon three</li>
    <li class="breakitem">Icon four</li>
    <li>Icon five</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be other more sensible solutions that will accomplish your goal.

Comment: Consider that someone with bad sight could be using 20px font size instead of the default 16px and then if you are hard-coding the 600px, you are making everything look horrible. Consider using a method which adapts to the content and to the user.

Comment: @Bouvanni Not following you.  My website is responive.  It has an \@media breakpoint at 600x for tablets.  I just need the latter items in my list to shift down under the previous items like a div float and want to do it easily.  Are \@media responsive breakpoints not being used anymore?

Comment: @CRAIG In that case just add `<br class="break-on-600" />` and `.break-on-600 { 
display: none; } @media (max-width: 600px) { .break-on-600 { display: initial; } }`

Comment: I'm still not understanding WHY you want this behavior...regardless, this smells like a job for display: flex on your ul. Then flex-wrapping and using flex-basis on your list items as needed.

Comment: Hi @thenomadicmann It is for an icon menu.  I updated my question.  I am not super familiar with display:flex.  Let me research that a bit.  I have previously did this with float:left, but looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps mate..

```css
  .container {
  width: 100vw;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  li:nth-of-type(4) {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="listing">
      <li>Item One</li>
      <li>Item twi</li>
      <li>Item three</li>
      <li></li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah it does!  I was hoping there would be a simpler way, but this works fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this:

```
.listing{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


@media(max-width: 600px){
.listing{
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
}
```